# Laravel : Web Api, how to find out if a user (application) is online?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am building a web service for mobile application by Laravel 5.8. I need to get the location of online users, search on some properties and send a notification to them.

The problem is I can't find out if a user is online. My solution was to keep pushing/receiving a message to applications every 10 seconds once they get connected for the first time. Clearly this approach has a huge overload on the server and is not practical.

I would be appreciated for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may make use of Real-time connections such as [Pusher](https://pusher.com/)

You would need presence channels to see who is online in JS, it works more client to client rather than the Laravel server knowing who is online.

You subscribe users to a channel and then you can see who else is on that channel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#presence-channels

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a column to your user table namely 'is_online' ?  So every time the user logged in set this field to true ? and when they are logged out or inactive for a specific of time you will set it to false ?

Comment: It is not practical, the application is real time

Comment: then you have to use websocket, or pusher for this one, you have to listen each user after they logged in. Please search for laravel echo and laravel broadcasting.